# Is it possible to strike-out terms in displayed equations?

Tags: formatting

I am looking for a typesetting capability similar to the LaTeX `cancel` package, resulting in something like this:

[image]

Can this be done?

Comment: closely related: [Is there a way to diagonally strike through a character](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/112397/5478)

Comment: Yes, close but not the same: I'd like to have labeled strikeouts, with labels that can potentially be anything (numbers, other equations, etc.), for cases where the struck out terms aren't just zero.

Comment: @Pirx - but the answer is going to be the same I think, you can either do it graphically, by overlaying an arrow on top of the text, creating an `Image`, or you can use the `MaTeX` typesetting package to just render the text.  The benefit of the latter option is that you can call the `cancel` package and not have to reinvent the wheel.  I would therefore call this a duplicate.

Comment: O.k., then, I'm O.K. with calling it a duplicate. I think in a sense the answer to my question is simply "no", since Mma typesetting is quite limited when compared to (La)TeX. A bit surprising perhaps, given that at least to me it looks like Mma's typesetting language is not that far from raw TeX. I'm not an expert, however, so it's quite possible I just don't know what I'm talking about on this topic...